# How to detect eventd using firebug/chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, browser

I wanted to know is it possible to find a  which file from several js files, responsible for an event that relates input field using firebug / chrome

If it is possible, how can I do it?

Suppose I have a page with 10 js files and a lot of code in them -
one of the files is responsible for a specific test in the input field.

How can I using firebug / chrome to find out what event is going on and what file it belongs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you're using Firebug:**

1. Open Firebug
2. Right-click the element in the HTML tab
3. Click on log events
4. Enable console tab
5. Click on Persist in the console tab (otherwise console tab will clear after the page is reloaded)
6. Select Closed (manually)

**If you're using Chrome developer tools:**

1. Ctrl + Shift + I (Developer Tools)
2. Scripts
3. Event Listener Breakpoints (on the right).

Answer (score 0):

In Firebug:

When you are on the Script tab, click the Pause button (which will start to pulse).

The next time an event happens it will breakpoint, allowing you to step into the function in question

Answer (score 0):

In firefox, debug with firebug.  Add breakpoints in your code

In chrome hit Ctrl-shift-i.  Add breakpoints within the scripts tag